# Does the dependence of errors on $\Delta x$ or $\Delta y$ really matter in the increment theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the following proof by Dr. Trefor  [here](https://youtu.be/9n0cRmmxkJw?list=PLHXZ9OQGMqxc_CvEy7xBKRQr6I214QJcd&t=487):

[image]

where each error term is a function of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ respectively.

However, consider the proof by [Thomas' Calculus](http://www.metcourses.com/Nisreen/Thomas_Calculus/CH19_APPENDIX/tcu11_appa7.pdf) where MVT is used to arrive at the following:

[image]

where $\epsilon_1$ is a function of $\Delta x$ and $\epsilon_2$ is a function of both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$.

I haven't found any situation where this difference caused a problem. So my question is, does the dependence of errors on $\Delta x$ or $\Delta y$ really matter?

Comment: suppose the two variable function $$f(x,y)=1+y^2$$  where is the effect of $\Delta x$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash I get what you're trying to say, so does it mean that both errors being functions of both deltas is the most general form?

Comment: In general, the error term is not going to be separable as a sum of functions only of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$. But for small $\Delta x, \Delta y$, it is approximately treatable as such a sum of functions, with an additional error term that is $O(\Delta x\Delta y)$, faster than either $\Delta x$ or $\Delta y$. Likely Dr. Trefor, who is certainly aware of the correct description, was thinking about this secondary approximation and failed to notice it was not exact. But it doesn't matter, because in both cases the error $\to 0$ as $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y \to 0$, which is all that is needed.